# What are gitmodules in Git?

Tags: git, github, octopress

I am just wondering what exactly gitmodules are. I heard that it is a file in your git folder but I can't find it. Does it have to exist? I already searched in various forums but I couldn't find a good explanation.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.gitmodules` file is a file in the repository created by the `git submodule` command (most commonly `git submodule add`) when using [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

It stores information about which directories certain external repositories should be mapped into, so that the `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` commands can know where to place them when someone clones the repository or asks for a submodule update.